# PHP SESSID starts automatically

Tags: php, session

I have default php.ini with session.auto_start=0

I have a simplest PHP script:

`<? print_r($_COOKIE); ?>`

Now...

If I load this script in Firefox and press F5 several times it shows empty array, which is as expected.

BUT if I do this in Chrome and press F5, it shows empty array, but the second time I do this it contains [PHPSESSID] => i7nocj03gkslj355g7o2tmk507

I also noticed that empty "sess_i7nocj03gkslj355g7o2tmk507" file was created.

I didn't start the session!
Anyone knows what's going on?

PHP Version 5.3.27, Apache 2.2

Comment: Probably you created a session before and then it got automatically destroyed by the server, but the cookie remains. Try creating a new session and then destroying it.

Comment: I did clear the cookies... it would be weird if it got restored using IP address although I have auto_start=0... anyway I have just updated to PHP 5.5 (php.ini remained unchanged) and Apache 2.4... and it is now working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Updated to PHP 5.5 and Apache 2.4 --- it now works as expected... (perhaps a bug)